# Robot Race - How can I make multiple robots race each other

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, nested-loops

So I have successfully implemented a one robot race where the user inputs a size representing a grid of NxN and the goal is for the robot to reach the top right of the grid taking a random number of steps ranging from 1 to N and is smart enough to change directions when facing a wall.

I must now however use the same class to implement a multiple robot race (at least 2 robots). The Robot class has the method called move() which takes two int parameters: (steps,gridSize) and moves the robot. My first thought was to create nested loops, one for each turn, and one for each robot, but am having trouble with it. I'd appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

Essentially, here is a sample output:

Move number 1:

- Robot 1 takes 2 steps and is at position x,y
- Robot 2 takes 3 steps and is at position x,y

Move number 2:

- Robot 1 ....
- Robot 2 ....

and so and and so forth.

Here is my main:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int gridSize, nRobo;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Reads user input for grid size. Must be at least 2.
    do{
        System.out.print("What is the size of your grid? (Must be at least 2)");
        gridSize = scanner.nextInt();
    }while(gridSize < 2);

    // Reads user input for number of Robots. Must be at least 1.
    do {
        System.out.println("\nHow many Robots will race? (Must have at least one robot in the race) ");
        nRobo = scanner.nextInt();
    }while( nRobo < 1);

    // Clears the line from the scanner before advancing(otherwise there is a bug in the loop).
    scanner.nextLine();

    Robot[] robo = new Robot[nRobo];

    // Name of each Robot
    for (int i = 0; i < robo.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Name of robot " + (i+1) + ": ");
        robo[i] = new Robot(scanner.nextLine());
    }
```

EDIT: and this is the logic I used for the 1 robot race (in a separate main):

```
    // Number of moves.
    int nMoves = 0;
    // While robot has not won, enter loop.
    while (!robo.won(gridSize)){

        //Steps is a random number between 1 and grid size.
        int steps = rand.nextInt(gridSize) + 1;
        System.out.println(" ==> Number of steps to take " + steps + ".");

        robo.move(steps,gridSize);

        System.out.println("\tResult: " + robo.toString());
        nMoves++;
    }

    System.out.println( "\n" + robo.getName() + " reached its final destination in  " +nMoves + " moves.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop inside the while loop for the `robo` array.

```
for (Robot r : robo) {
    int steps = rand.nextInt(gridSize) + 1;
    System.out.println(r.getName() + " takes " + steps + " steps.");
    r.move(steps,gridSize);
    System.out.println("\tResult: " + r.toString());
}
nMoves++;
```

Comment: I get an out of bounds exception